# Ubuntu 22.04 stuck on booting/loading screen

Tags: boot, 22.04

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on kernel version 5.15.0-41-generic. I am stuck on booting/loading screen, every other stage works fine.

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: The same problem

Comment: @excelsiorious My solution is to delete the /etc/fstab entry for the swap (partition).